# spawn process in win XP

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to create a automated ftp log in script in Expect/TCL.

This is my script

```
   spawn ftp 100.100.100.1 
   expect ".*:"
   send "username"
   expect ".*:"
   send "password"
   expect ".*>"
```

I get an error in Windows XP saying , it encountered an error and needs to close . 
But same thing work on a windows 2000 .

Can anyone guide me .

Comment: Could you describe, what version of tcl and expect are you using? Is this ActiveState TCL or Cygwin?

Comment: I am using activestate TCL 8.4 and Expect 5.4 on Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to launch your script with wish instead of tclsh? It might make a different.

Reference: http://wiki.tcl.tk/3548